# Time complexity for concatenating strings

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was going through this text from [Cracking the Coding Interview](https://books.google.be/books?id=7Ui4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false) and something doesn't look clear to me:

> ### Arrays and Strings
>
> ```java
> String joinWords(String[] words) {
>   String sentence = "";
>   for (String w : words) {
>     sentence = sentence + w;
>   }
>   return sentence;
> }
> ```
>
> On each concatenation, a new copy of the string is created, and the two strings are copied over, character by character. The first iteration requires us to copy  characters. The second iteration requires copying 2 characters. The third iteration requires 3, and so on. The total time therefore is ( + 2 + ... + ). This reduces to (²).
>
> Why is it (²)? Because 1 + 2 + ... + n equals (+1)/2, or (²).

How does ( + 2 + ) reduce to (²)?

My analogy, assuming  is a constant 1, then  is 2( + 2) == 3

From the book (2²) == 4 assuming  is a constant 1

Is the algorithm analysis in the above code correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the above calculation O(x + 2x + ... + nx)

`x + 2x + ... + nx is expanded as x(n(n+1)/2)`

which is x((n^2+n/2)) since we neglect constants and in time complexity calculation and take the value with the largest power value it is taken as (2).

It is similar to taking (3) as ().

To rationalize how asymptotic notations ignore constant factors, I usually think of it like this: asymptotic complexity isn't for comparing the performance of different algorithms, it's for understanding how the performance of individual algorithms scales with respect to the input size.

For instance, we say that a function that takes 3 steps is (), because, roughly speaking, for large enough inputs, doubling the input size will no more than double the number of steps taken. Similarly, (2) means that doubling the input size will at most quadruple the number of steps, and (log) means that doubling the input size will increase the number of steps by at most some constant.

It's a tool for saying which algorithms scale better, not which ones are absolutely faster.

For more info : https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-leave-the-constants-while-calculating-time-complexity-for-algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the book's analysis is roughly correct, although it silently assumes all words have the same length *x*.

You are right that 2(+2) == 3, while the book's formula gives 2² == 4, but in big- notation we don't look at the exact value, but the order of magnitude.

There are ½(+1) characters copied. This is because the expression 1+2+...+ is a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), equal to ½(+1). Only remains to multiply with .

For  == 1 and  == 2 it gives your result, i.e. 3

We can write this as ½² + ½. Now, when we go to big- notation, only the most significant term needs to be retained, and any constant coefficient can be dropped, and so:

[½² + ½] == [½²] == (²)

Obviously this means that the expression will give a different value for a given  and , but in big- notation that is not what is the point. It gives an order of magnitude.